# web page not displaying properly in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, doctype

I know this is a well-known issue in web design. My web site works as expected on Firefox, Opera and Safary but on IE the original design is lost. There is something wrong with the container as you can see in: [www.skaldenmet.cjb.net](http://www.skaldenmet.cjb.net)

I'm aware the coding is not that good, but I would like someone to tell me where does exactly the problem lies so I don't have to re-design everything from the scratch.

I hope someone can help. Thanks in advance!

HTML SOURCE

```
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="icon" href="favicon.jpg" type="image/x-icon" />
  <link href="skaldenmet-css.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <title>Skaldenmet-Folk Metal</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="header"></div>
    <div id="navigation">

        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html">Inicio</a></li>
            <li><a href="history.html">Historia</a></li>
            <li><a href="music.html">Música</a></li>
            <li><a href="band.html">Banda</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.html">Contacto</a></li>

            <li><a href="license.html">Licencia CC</a></li>
            <li><a href="links.html">Enlaces</a></li>
            <li><a href="english.html">English</a></li>
            <li><a href="news.html">Noticias</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div style="text-align: justify; background-image: url('bg55.jpg');">


            <h1>Bienvenidos a Skaldenmet,</h1>  
           <div style="text-indent: 160px;">  un proyecto folk metal desde el norte de Argentina.</div>
        <div style="padding: 5px;">
        <p>     
            En este sitio encontrarán información sobre la banda así como la posibilidad de descargar 
            <a href="music.html" title="Descargar el disco">"Bosque bajo la noche"</a>, el primer, y tal vez último, disco lanzado.<br>
        </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
        <p>2010-2011 | www.skaldenmet.cjb.net | Republica Argentina </p>
        <p>Content on this site is licensed under a <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/">Creative Commons Attribution 3.0 License</a></p>
        <p>Sitio desarrollado con software libre <a href="http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU/Linux">GNU/Linux</a>.</p>
    </div>

  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS FILE

```
@CHARSET "ISO-8859-1";
*
    {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }
    body
    {
        font-family:    Optima, Ã¢â‚¬ËœLucida GrandeÃ¢â‚¬â„¢, Ã¢â‚¬ËœLucida Sans UnicodeÃ¢â‚¬â„¢, Verdana, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size:      12px; color: #000;
        text-align:     center;
        padding:        12px 0;
        background:     #FCFCFC;
    }
    #container
    {
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 800px;
        background:#fff;
        border-width: 2px;
        border-style:solid; 
    }
    #header
    {
        background-image: url(header2.jpg);
        background-repeat: repeat;
        width:800px;
        height: 200px;              
    }
    #header h1
    {
        text-align:right;
        padding-top: 80px;
        padding-right: 20px;

    }

    #navigation 
    {
        float: left;
        width: 800px;
        background: #333;

    }

    #navigation ul 
    {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0; 
    }

    #navigation ul li 
    {
        list-style-type: none;
        display: inline;
    }

    #navigation li a
    {
        display: block;
        float: left;
        padding: 5px 10px;
        color: #fff;
        text-decoration: none;
        border-right: 1px solid #fff;
    }

    #navigation li a:HOVER 
    {
        background: #383;
    }

    #content-container, #content-container-index
    {
        clear:left;
        background-image: url("bg55.jpg");
        height: 400px;

    }

    /* esto no se si es necesario */
    #content-container 
    {
        padding:20px;
    }

    #content-image{
        width: 780px;
        text-align: justify;

    }
    #content-container h2
    {
        color:#000;
        font-size: 160%;
        margin: 0 0 .5em;
    }

    #footer {
        background-image: url(footer.jpg);
        background-repeat: repeat;
        height: 50px;  
    }

a:link { 
    color: #333333;
    }
a:visited { 
    color: #333333;
    }
a:hover { 
    color: #CCCCCC;
    background-color: #333333;
    text-decoration: none;
    }
a:active { 
    color: #333333;
    }
```

Comment: Please: provide us a screenshot for people that do not have installed Internet Explorer. Also, what version of IE are you running? Where do you think the problem is, and reduce your question to that specific issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a doctype as the very first line to trigger Standards Mode:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Without it, IE is rendering your page in [Quirks Mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode) (*which emulates IE5.5*).

See: http://hsivonen.iki.fi/doctype/

I'm not intimately familiar with your site, but after manually changing the browser mode to IE9 mode just to test (hit F12), it looks "identical" to Chrome.

Comment: your answer came  a few seconds after I posted the question =)

Comment: Indeed. Your comment `"I know this is a well-known issue in web design."` was true; it is quite common. Seeing "problem with IE" and `<html>` as the very first line made the problem jump out at me.